# JQuery filter rows of gridview inside an update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, updatepanel

I have two combo boxes and a gridview on a page, changing the values in the combo boxes changes the data displayed in the gridview.

I also have a textbox which is used to filter the data in the gridview using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        $('#filter').keyup(function () {
            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).text());
            }).show();
        })
    } (jQuery));
});
```

This all works fine except that when the user changes the values in the combo boxes a postback occurs in order to refresh the table data and the screen flashes as it is refreshed, which is not desirable

I have wrapped the controls in an update panel and included a scriptmanager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM_Items" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_Items" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        //Controls in here

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This has stopped the page flashing and the table is still being populated, but the filter textbox which is inside the update panel no longer works.

I have tried moving the script inside the update panel but this made no difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your filter event is registered to the filter textbox before it has been asynchronously reloaded with the update panel. Registering directly onto the #filter with .keyup is a onetime event. If the textbox is removed or added again it will not have the event handler attached to it.

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#filter', function () {

});
```